# jquery.js: Failed to load resource - Works on loca but no on website

Tags: jquery, azure-web-app-service

**The problem:**

At this moment I'm receiving the following error while loading pages that require jquery to work:

[image]

I've checked if this also happens while working on local and **yes, it shows the same error message but the jquery code executes normally, which is weird**.

**Validations:**

I've checked if the file is loaded in both enviroments.

For the online project:

[image]

It seems the file is located in the correct place, but then I click on the folder, the name in the address appears as j**Q**uery although the folder name is j**q**uery. I would thank any suggestions on how to solve this.

**Update:**

This is one of the views that present the problem. It's worth to mention that the reference for the jquery files is being made from the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

</environment>
```

Finally, this is the code of the view for exemplification:

```
model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Store>
@using Application.Models
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
@Html.Partial("_NavBar")
<h2>Tiendas</h2>

<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" data-target="#modal-action-store"
        class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Nueva Tienda
        </a>
</div>
<p></p>
<table id="stores" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tienda
            </th>
            <th>
                Dirección
            </th>
            <th>
                Área
            </th>
            <th>
                Distrito
            </th>
            <th>
                Cadena
            </th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreArea)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Districts.DistrictName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreChains.ChainName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="modalbuttonedit">
                        <a id="editStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create"
                            data-target="#modal-action-store" asp-route-id="@item.StoreID" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.Partial("_Modal", new BootstrapModel
{
    ID = "modal-action-store",
    AreaLabeledId = "modal-action-store-label",
    Size = ModalSize.Medium
})
@section scripts{
<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var global = this;
    var wasclicked = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            global.wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            global.wasclicked = 0;
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
            $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
                var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
                $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#DistrictID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                        items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code to see what might cause the issue?

Comment: Sure! I'll edit the post to add it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to load is located in the `lib/jquery/dist/` folder, spelled as j**q**uery and you are browsing the files located at `lib/jQuery/dist/` spelled as j**Q**uery.

It wouldn't be best practice to have two files with the same name, even though one is capitalized and the other isn't.

Comment: I saw that too, but as is shown in the picture, there are 2 jquery folders: jQuery and jquery, both of them have the required file.

Comment: See my updated answer (better explained), why try to get into issues?

Comment: I changed the name of the jQuery folder to Test. I have to be honest, I don't know why when I click on the jquery folder, in the site address appears as jQuery. https://i.imgur.com/joKGunI.png